# Spreadsheet sidebar created using HtmlService not able to call the app script code

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-api, gmail-api

I made an app script code that make a interactive side bar which consists of a box and a submit button. On pressing the submit button it is supposed to call a function in my GS file but it only works if I give it the scope https://mail.google.com/ .However google add-on support is asking me to use https://www.googleapis.com/gmail.modify .I have tried running all the functions and google apis I am using individually using the modify scope and they are all working fine, but when grouped the html script doesn't hit my script code.

**manifest file**

```
{
  "timeZone": "Asia/Kolkata",
  "dependencies": {
    "enabledAdvancedServices": [
      {
        "userSymbol": "Gmail",
        "version": "v1",
        "serviceId": "gmail"
      },
      {
        "userSymbol": "Sheets",
        "version": "v4",
        "serviceId": "sheets"
      }
    ]
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
  ],
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "sheets": {
    "macros": [
      {
        "menuName": "onInstall",
        "functionName": "onInstall"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**sidebar.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>
<script>
  function doPost() {
   var ignorelist = document.getElementById('IgnoreList').value;
   google.script.run.extractEmailAndAddToSheet(ignorelist);
 }
</script>

<body>
  <div>
    <label>Emails from below senders will be ignored</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="IgnoreList" rows="25" style="width: 100%;resize: none; zoom:100%" onwheel="this.style.zoom = parseInt(this.style.zoom) + event.deltaY * 0.001 + '%'"><?= message1 ?></textarea>
    <button type="submit", style="width: 100%; height: 50px; font-size: 20px;",style="width: 100%; height: 50px; font-size: 20px;" onclick="doPost();">Submit</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**code.gs**

```
function onInstall() {
  onOpen()
}
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp
    .getUi()
    .createMenu("7Targets GMail™ Contacts Extractor")
    .addItem("7Targets GMail™ Contacts Extractor", "showSidebar")
    .addToUi();
}

function showSidebar() {
  var original_ignore_email_list = get_active_user_org();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("drawer");
  template.message1 = original_ignore_email_list;
  var html = template.evaluate().setTitle("Extract Contacts from GMail");
  ui.showSidebar(html);
}

function extractEmailAndAddToSheet(ignore_email_list) {
  var user_email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  Logger.log("Sheet activated" + sheet);
  Logger.log("logging the emails to be ignored: " + ignore_email_list);
  var start_index = 0;
  do {
    var emails = GmailApp.search("newer_than:100000d AND in:inbox", 0, 2);
    start_index = start_index + 500;
    var label = "Scanned";
    GmailApp.createLabel(label);
    var label_id = get_label_id(user_email, label);
    Logger.log("Label id " + label_id);
    var messages = [];
    var no_of_messages_per_email = [];
    for (var i = emails.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      messages = messages.concat(emails[i].getMessages());
      emails[i].getMessages().forEach(function () { no_of_messages_per_email.push(emails[i].getMessages().length); })
    }
    Logger.log("Logging no of emails: " + emails.length);
    Logger.log("Logging no of threads: " + messages.length);

    for (var m = 0; m < messages.length; m++) {
      var message_id = messages[m].getId();
      var check = check_if_message_has_label(user_email, message_id, label_id);
      if (check) {
        continue;
      }


      var from_email = messages[m].getFrom();
      Logger.log("data obtained from 'from' section: " + from_email);

      var plain_email_body = messages[m].getPlainBody();

      var from_email_id = process_from_mail(from_email, sheet, plain_email_body, ignore_email_list);
      Logger.log("From section processing completed");

      var to_mail = messages[m].getTo();
      Logger.log("data obtained from 'to' section: " + to_mail);
      process_to_mail(to_mail, sheet, ignore_email_list, no_of_messages_per_email[i], user_email, from_email_id);
      Logger.log("To section processing completed");

      var cc = messages[m].getCc();
      Logger.log("data obtained from 'cc' section: " + cc);
      process_cc_mail(cc, sheet, ignore_email_list);
      Logger.log("CC section processing completed");

      add_label_to_message(user_email, message_id, label_id);

    }
  }
  while (start_index < 5000);
}
```

Thanks for the help in advance

Comment: I think your error is in your server code `extractEmailAndAddToSheet`.  Please include that in your post.

Comment: You can use the function name doPost() in your Javascript if you wish but it is not going to become an endpoint like the one in Google Apps Script.

Comment: @TheWizEd thanks for replying, the current code is not even reaching the extractEmailAndAddToSheet code block so I'll add the makeui, extractEmailAndAddToSheet and onInstall code. Please let me know what you think of it. Thanks

Comment: `in doPost()` put an `alert("Hello")` just before `var ignorelist` and `alert(ignorelist)` just after.

Comment: @TheWizEd it didn't work, on hitting the submit button on the UI using the following scopes
"oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.container.ui",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
  ]
doesn't yield any results but if I use https://mail.google.com/, it starts working

Comment: In the editor you have enabled Gmail Service, right?

Comment: @TheWizEd yes I have added my manifest file please refer that

Comment: Sorry, i've run out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

gs:

```
function lfunko(m) {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(m);
}

function launchTheDialog() {
  let t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("ah2");
  t.message1 = "Get up sleep head.";
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(t.evaluate());
}
```

html: ("ah2.html");

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <base target="_top">
</head>
<script>
  function pform() {
   var ignorelist = document.getElementById('IgnoreList').value;
   google.script.run.lfunko(ignorelist);
 }
</script>

<body>
  <div>
    <label>Emails from below senders will be ignored</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="IgnoreList" rows="25" style="width: 100%;resize: none; zoom:100%" onwheel="this.style.zoom = parseInt(this.style.zoom) + event.deltaY * 0.001 + '%'"><?= message1 ?></textarea>
    <button type="button" style="width: 100%; height: 50px; font-size: 20px;",style="width: 100%; height: 50px; font-size: 20px;" onclick="pform();">Submit</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for replying tried it didn't work, the function inside gs file is not being called for some reason